# JAX WS wsdl generation - how to change the service name

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, jboss7.x

Server: JBoss 7.1
Java: 7 (JAX-WS version: 2.2.4-b01)

Ex1:

```
@Name("CustomerServices")
@Stateless
@WebService
public class CustomerServices{ ... }
```

Ex2:

```
@Name("CustomerServices")
@Stateless
@WebService(servicename="CustomerServices")
public class CustomerServices { ... }
```

When the JBOSS generated the wsdl files throught JAX-WS the wsdl looks like:

Ex1:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
...
    <wsdl:service name="CustomerServicesService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:CustomerServicesServiceSoapBinding"> 
            <soap:address location="<host>:<port>/<ejb-context>/CustomerServices"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Ex2:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
...
    <wsdl:service name="CustomerServices">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:CustomerServicesServiceSoapBinding"> 
            <soap:address location="<host>:<port>/<ejb-context>/CustomerServicesService/CustomerServicesService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

So my question is, how to get this output?

```
<wsdl:definitions>
...
  <wsdl:service name="CustomerServices">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CustomerServicesServiceSoapBinding"> 
    <soap:address location="<host>:<port>/<ejb-context>/CustomerServices"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The service name must be **CustomerServices** and not CustomerServicesService and the address location must be **../CustomerServices**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@WebContext(contextRoot = "<ejb-context>", urlPattern = "/CustomerServices")
```

Also you can set the portType to something else (i.e: `<wsdl:portType name="MyCustomerServices">` this will be the name of your port interface when generating the client) using:

```
@WebService(name = "MyCustomerServices", serviceName = "CustomerServices")
```

Comment: I post a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864496/jboss-7-1-how-to-a-module