# JBoss 7.1 How to add a module

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, jboss7.x

I use the annotation @WebContext in my project using JBoss 7.1.

This annotation is present in a JBOSS module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.ws.api">
```

The jar is located in JBOSS\modules\jboss\ws\api (jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar)

I'm not using maven so how do I include this dependency? Can I use the jboss-deployment-structure or Dependencies in the MANIFEST?

My point is to have access to the jar in my Lib. Ideally the jar jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar must be located in JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs.

I have already try to have the dependency in the MANIFEST and jboss-deployment_structure bu of course with that JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs isn't updated.

I think the file standalone.xml must be updated in order to add this module. Please explain to me how I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add a dependency if its not automatically included.

If the org.jboss.ws.api not automatic( you will find out when you deploy to the server ),  and I don't see why it wouldn't be, adding it via the jboss-deployment-structure.xml is the way to go. 
That file should be included in your WEB-INF directory, along with your web.xml and jboss-web.xml files.

See [AS7 Classloading Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7)  on the jboss-deployment-structure.xml if need be.

Comment: I have edited my question. What I want is to have JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs updated with the module jar jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar. I have already try the others solutions but I think I must look at the file standalone.xml. Please have a new look at the question. Thanks

Comment: I don't think I really understand your question but I will give it a try: You should add the dependency to that jar manually in your IDE, but not in the manifest, because JBoss 7 has that dependency already (I think is the `<extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>` that does the trick). So, in example, if you were using maven, you'll have to declare that dependency as "provided" and not "compile" or "runtime". Are you using eclipse?

Comment: I agree with @donsenior . If you are looking to leverage that at compile time, then you will need to add a reference( Under Eclipse, this is handled by referencing a JBoss Server instance within your Dynamic Web Project ).  However, since that is part of the JBoss server itself, you just need reference it in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml.  Again, you shouldn't have to do anything special for utilizing the `@WebContext` annotation.  Its baked in and requires no extra dependencies at deployment time.

Comment: I use eclipse. I already have the extension <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/> in my standalone file, but the import org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext isn't available. Well, It's correct because the JAR jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar isn't "yet" loaded into the JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs. My question is: There is a way to automatically load this jar/module into JBoss 7.1 Runtime to be able to use it or should I just import this jar into my lib?

Comment: Try using `org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext` and not `org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext` since JBoss 7 is using JBossWS 4.0, and _org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.*_ was moved to _org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.*_ from JBossWS 3.4.x to JBoss 4.0.x. Take a look [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS4MigrationGuide)

Comment: Yes of course, my mistake. I use of course org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext instead of org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext because it's JBoss7 but either way I don't this import available because I have not this jar in the  JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs. Do you use JBOSS 7.1 and have this import available?

Comment: In https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments the Subsystem responsible for adding the implicit dependency is the Web Services Subsystem but I already have this extension. What I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean with "JBoss 7.1 Runtime Libs"? JBoss loads modules from the "modules" directory. In this case, it load the WebContext class from "modules/org/jboss/ws/api/main/jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"...

Comment: I mean the Server Library [JBoss 7.1 Runtime] used from the Java Build Path like `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.runtime.runtimeTarget/JBoss 7.1 Runtime">` in my classpath

Comment: But aren't those dependencies of the JBoss Eclipse Plugin? Not dependencies of the JBoss AS... try to add the dependency you need manually: Right Clik on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JAR -> (Browse to modules/org/jboss/ws/api/main/jbossws-api-1.0.0.GA.jar)

Comment: OK, That's my point. I already do that and it's working perfectly. My question is if it's the best way to do that? Adding the jar manually when perhaps I can add it via others standard ways like editing the standalone ... I don't know ...

Comment: No, because the JBoss AS knows nothing about eclipse! You need to do that manually because Eclipse needs it for compile time, but your app doesn't need it because in runtime, the server will provide it... That's why you want to use a build tool such as Maven, for not having configure your eclipse manually! ;)

Comment: OK, so there is no way to add this dependency via standalone or other dependency file? I 'm wondering how the Server Library [JBoss 7.1 Runtime] is built. Which modules are included here and how to customize? Please check `https://community.jboss.org/message/759251` which use also a maven repo to get this jar.

Comment: Think it this way: the standalone is a server configuration file. Your eclipse needs that dependency for building your app (because you import that dependency) but your eclipse knows nothing about JBoss (maybe the plugin does for basic JBoss Management), but what if you decide to deploy your WS in weblogic or tomcat (changing some dependencies to nothing JBoss specific like JAX-WS or Apache CXF)? I don't know how the JBoss Eclipse Plugin works, I don't use it, I do start and stop the server by command line, and deploy-undeploy by maven plugin or JBoss Console. Sorry I can't help you with that

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse preference if you go under Server-->RuntimeEnv-->DefaultClaspathEntry. You can add additional  modules. I had to add org.jobss.ws.api.